# mvn clean install works on springboot 1.3.1 but not on 2.2.2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have application named A with two submodules under it 
A-lib 
A-test (where all the tests reside)

A-test module has some code dependency to A-lib so in A-test/pom.xml I have this.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.mypackagename</groupId>
<artifactId>A-lib</artifactId>
<version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm trying to move from springboot 1.3.1 to 2.2.2.

On A-test module, mvn clean install command works fine on 1.3.1 but throwing some dependency error when I tried on 2.2.2.
It says that it cannot find some symbols that reside under A-lib.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) on project A-test: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] MyClassInTest.java:[20,50] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class MyClassInLib
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone please advise?

Comment: I would try to upgrade maven-compiler-plugin to 3.8.1

Comment: Not only check the java and maven version, 
but also which version of java is used by maven.

Comment: I have tried with 3.8.1 with java 1.8
`<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>`

Comment: You are upgrading from Spring Boot 1.X to 2.X and expect everything works. There have been a large number of changes in dependencies etc. The question is: Is the error message about the compile issue within your own code? If so you have to show the full code which I have my doubts otherwise the old could not have been compiled without any issue..

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE requires Java 8 and Maven 3.3+ so check the version of maven

Comment: You have tried with the version of maven-compiler-plugin 3.8.1 but not with Maven version 3.3+